# IDP that supports SAML 2.0 HTTP Artifact Binding?

Tags: saml-2.0, shibboleth, idp

I setup a demo showing SSO using Shibboleth SP3 and Azure AD as the IDP. This worked great. I am now hoping to build off this and demo HTTP Artifact bindings but this is not supported with Azure AD.

What's an IDP the supports this? Preferably as a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may look at the free IdP of SSO Circle - https://www.ssocircle.com/en/idp-tips-tricks/ssocircle-how-to/

IdP meta data can be found at https://idp.ssocircle.com/